# How to print from python for statement only 1 time each item

Tags: python, for-loop

I am parsing a json string in python, and try to get "categorys" from there.
Let's say that string contains following data:

```
Apple
Pear
Apple
Melon
Apple
Pear
Melon
Melon
```

Now i want them to be printed out, but only **one time** each category.

At the moment my code parses string, and prints out multiple times these categories, something like this

```
Apple
Apple
Apple
Pear
Pear
Melon
Melon
Melon
```

**But i want it to print:**

```
Apple
Pear
Melon
```

My code:

```
match=re.compile('"category_name":"(.+?)"').findall(link)
for category in match:
        print('%s'%(category))
```

How could i do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does the json look like? Also does order matter?

Comment: `for category in match:` instead `for category in set(match):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `for` loop to following -

```
for category in set(match):
    print('%s'%(category))
```

A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects. Check [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Answer (score 0):

I did use `set` which by default remove the duplicates.

```
match=re.compile('"category_name":"(.+?)"').findall(link)
m = set(match)
for category in m:
        print('%s'%(category))
```